# Insert or update value on table where values can be repeated multiple times

Tags: postgresql

Previously I was using the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Users(user BIGINT PRIMARY KEY, 
                   item_count INT);
```

which allowed me to do a simple upsert:

```
INSERT INTO Users(user, item_count) 
VALUES($1, $2) 
ON CONFLICT(user) DO 
UPDATE SET item_cout = user.item_count + 1;
```

However I want to switch my table to have more columns so each user have a different item_count per server so I did:

```
CREATE TABLE Users(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
                   server BIGINT NOT NULL,  
                   user BIGINT NOT NULL,  
                   item_count INT);
```

However I'm not allowed to do an ON CONFLICT anymore in this case because neither server nor user are unique, and they can be repeated throughout the table for example:

```
id  server  user  item_count
1        1    1           95
2        2    1          345
3        1    2          594
4        3    1            0
```

Is there any way to do an upsert with the second table instead of separating the query into two statements? (one for insert if not exists and one for updating)

Comment: *I'm not allowed to do an ON CONFLICT anymore in this case because neither server nor user are unique* For ON CONFLICT you must have unique index by the expression which is unique for current entity stored in this table. In case you tell about the `(server, user)` combination is unique, so you must create unique index `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_server_user ON users (server, user)`, or/and backward `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_user_server ON users (user, server)`.

Comment: Of course, you can specify this condition directly in *conflict_target* attribute of ON CONFLICT clause. But I don't recommend - unique index (or constraint) absence is integrity violation possibility.

Comment: `user` is a reserved keyword. You **have** to double quote it if you want to column with that name `"user"` - but it would be better to find a different name for that column.